# nasm function _system never executed?

Tags: macos, assembly, call, x86-64, nasm

I am working on a mac and writing an asm program supposed to printf its own source in another file with some modification, itself compile and run it. Therefor, I use the function system() to run a bash command.
Here is my problem, the line call _system works at a line, but a few lines later, nothing happen, its call seems to be ignored.
I made tests to be sure everything is fine, and it looks to be, I don't get error or whatever ... here is a sample :

```
section .data

    i: equ 5
[...]
    s_string: equ $ - string
    name: db "Sully_%d.s", 0
    s_name: equ $ - name
    cc: db "nasm -fmacho64 Sully_%1$d.s -o Sully_%1$d.o", 0
    s_cc: equ $ - cc
    link: db "ld Sully_%1$d.o -o Sully_%1$d -macosx_version_min 10.8 -lSystem", 0
    s_link: equ $ - link
    ex: db "./Sully_%d", 0
    s_ex: equ $ - ex
    tmp: db "ls -l", 0

section .text
    global start
    global _main
    extern _sprintf
    extern _dprintf
    extern _printf
    extern _system
    extern _close
    extern _strlen

start:
    call _main
    ret

_main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 16
    sub rsp, 0x650                  ; 1616 byte to store strings later
    mov rbx, i
    cmp rbx, 0
    je end_point
    mov rdi, qword [rsi]
    call _strlen
    mov r12, rax
load_name:
    lea rdi, [rbp + 16]
    lea rsi, [rel name]              ; string in data section, work fine since I can print it later at rbp + 16 location, I mean the result of 'name' string format with i as parameter
    cmp r12, 7
    jne ln_mov_i
    mov rdx, i
    cmp r12, 7
    je ln_mov_i_1
ln_mov_i:
    mov rdx, i - 1
ln_mov_i_1:
    xor rax, rax
    call _sprintf
    cmp rax, 0
    jl ret
load_cc:
    lea rdi, [rel tmp]
    call _system                      ; this does work

    lea rdi, [rbp + 32 + s_name]      ; string in data section, work fine since I can print it later
    lea rsi, [rel cc]
    cmp r12, 7
    jne lc_mov_i
    mov rdx, i
    cmp r12, 7
    je lc_mov_i_1
lc_mov_i:
    mov rdx, i - 1
lc_mov_i_1:
    xor rax, rax
    call _sprintf
    cmp rax, 0
    jl ret
    lea rdi, [rel tmp]
    call _system                    ; this doesn't work
[...]
```

I noticed with a few more tests than system return 32512 which is if I well understand, 127. I tried to use sh -c 'my command' but it doesn't make any better thing ...

With dtruss, i found out that the call of posix_spawn fail, I don't know why, here is what I find for the 2 call _system of my sample :

```
 PID/THRD         RELATIVE  ELAPSD  CPU SYSCALL(args)                                                    = return
 3040/0x143a1:      2271     243    240 posix_spawn(0x7FFEEFBFF454, 0x7FFF5BDBD256, 0x7FFEEFBFF360)      = 0 0
 3040/0x143a1:      2492     157    153 posix_spawn(0x7FFEEFBFF454, 0x7FFF5BDBD256, 0x7FFEEFBFF360)      = -1 Err#14
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't work ! I can't find on the internet any specification about this function 'system'.

Comment: Use a debugger and/or a tool to trace system-calls.  (On Linux I'd use `strace ./a.out` to see what system calls the `system` library function made.  If it didn't crash, presumably the command just exited.)  On Linux there's even `ltrace` to trace library function calls, but IDK if Mac has that.

Comment: I tried but I cannot really understand the result of it , using dtruss or dtrace on macos, I found out this : 
posix_spawn(0x7FFEEFBFF444, 0x7FFF5BDBD256, 0x7FFEEFBFF350)   = -1 Err#14
That occur at the moment the function _system is running

Comment: dtruss and dtrace can't dereference those pointer args and print the strings?  `strace` does that by default (and it's *extremely* helpful sometimes, like oh I passed a bad pointer, or it holds the wrong contents).  Also to decode error returns into `-EFAULT`, `-ENOENT`, or other errno codes.  Also *extremely* helpful.  Maybe one of the OS X tools has options for those.  But at least that tells you that `system` did run as far as trying to make a system call.